# Validate array if already exists in mysql php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cyberduck

Currently I have set of array.

and

I can easily insert these data to my database using `Laravel` without doing any validations

here's the sample array

CODE:

```
        $excel1 = Importer::make('Excel');
        $excel1->hasHeader(true);
        $excel1->load($savePath.$fileName);
        $excel1->setSheet(2);
        $collection1 = $excel1->getCollection();
        $arr1 = json_decode($collection1,true);

    foreach ($arr1 as $row1) {
                $insert_data1[] = array(
                    'projCode'  =>  $projCode,
                    'emp_id'  =>  $row1['company_id'],
                    'type'  =>  'EMP',
                    'deleted'  =>  0,
                    'by_id'  => auth()->user()->id,
                    'updated_by'    =>  auth()->user()->name,
                    'created_at'    =>  now(),
                    'updated_at'    => now(),
                );
            }
  dd($insert_data1);
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

and I'm using this code to insert these data to my table

```
    DB::table('tbl_emp_proj')->insert($insert_data1);
```

and this works fine but the problem is,

I'm trying to validate if `emp_id` exists or not in my `users` table

Here's my `users` table

[image]

The value of `emp_id` from array should check if it already exists in my `users` using `company_id` field from `users`. How can I validate it if `$insert_data1` is an array and should be check if it exists on database?

**UPDATE**

currently i have this validator and I tried to add up the `$Insert_data1` but gives me `undefined var for $insert_data1`.

```
      $validator = Validator::make(
        [
            'file'      => $request->file,
            'extension' => strtolower($request->file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
        ],
        [
            'file'          => 'required|max:5000',
            'extension'      => 'required|in:,csv,xlsx,xls',
        ],
        $insert_data1,
        [
            '*.emp_id' => "required|exists:users,company_id",
        ]
    );
```

Comment: How are you getting those data for `foreach` loop?

Comment: I updated my question. I'm using `cyber-duck/excel/import` library. The foreach data is coming from the data of an excel file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Laravel `Validator` to validate any arrays as if its a request input.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make(
    $insert_data1,
    [
        '*.emp_id' => "required|integer|exists:users,company_id",
    ]
);
```

EDIT:

You can receive error messages and error items with the validator APIs.

```php
$failed = $validator->fails(); //boolean

$errors = $validator->errors();

$validated = $validator->validated();

$invalid = $validator->invalid();
```

Comment: Can I make `integer` to something like string? because the `company_id/emp_id` contains symbols

Comment: yes you can. its all as per your need and setup. what I mentioned there is just an example

Comment: I have undefined var `$insert_data1` I just add up your answer to my current `validator`

Comment: put the validator check after the completion of foreach loop preparing the `$insert_data1`. else, verify the variable name is not having any type there.

Comment: as of now Im using `$validator->fails();` seems like `insert_data1` in my `validator1`  doesn't recognize the var `$insert_data1` from my foreach

Comment: define the variable prior to foreach start `$insert_data1 = [];` followed by your foreach.

Comment: This one workssss, I tried to validate and gives me `The selected 1.emp_id is invalid.` it works fine. Can I rename the error message?  I'm usign this code `if($validator->fails()){
                    return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->with(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()])
                    ->with('modal',$modal);
                }`